# GDAL CreateFeature doesn't add a Feature to the Layer

Tags: python, gis, gdal, ogr, osgeo

I'm running Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 17.10, with osgeo v2.2.1 installed via apt.

My code loads osgeo and 1) tries to create a shapefile with 1 layer and 1 field, 2) create a polygon (4 points geometry), then 3) add the polygon to the shapefile's layer.
Everything runs without trouble until the third function when I use layer.CreateFeature(feature) :

```
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
ds = driver.Open(shapefile_name,-1)
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
layer = ds.GetLayer()
print "layer",layer,", number of features :",layer.GetFeatureCount()
```

This prints :

```
layer <osgeo.ogr.Layer; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'OGRLayerShadow *' at 0x7f79aa499c90> > , number of features : 0
```

I then create a geometry from the polygon I already created and passed to the function beforehand :

```
defn = layer.GetLayerDefn()

geom = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkb(poly)
print "geom",geom
```

This prints :

```
geom POLYGON ((-106 24 0,-100 26 0,-103 20 0,-106 20 0))
```

Code then goes on to create the feature :

```
feat = ogr.Feature(defn)
feat.SetField('polygon_id', polygon_name)
feat.SetGeometry(geom)
print feat
print "Created feature",feat.GetField('polygon_id')
```

This feature is created :

```
<osgeo.ogr.Feature; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'OGRFeatureShadow *' at 0x7f35cd988d50> >
Created feature polygon_1
```

But when I add it to the layer, nothing happens :

```
layer.CreateFeature(feat)
print "number of features : ",layer.GetFeatureCount()
```

Prints :

```
number of features :  0
```

What did I miss ?

Comment: Does it help if you flush first (`ds.FlushCache()`), or close the file and reopen?

Comment: Thank you for your interest in my question.
The function I'm creating the shapefile and its layer in ends with
`driver = ds = layer = None`
And the shapefile and layer are attributed right before creating the geometry (as shown) ; I tried to FlushCache the driver anyway at several places, including :
`feat.SetGeometry(geom)
ds.FlushCache()
layer.CreateFeature(feat)`

I also tried ResetReading the layer after the fist GetFeatureCount
`print "layer",layer,", number of features :",layer.GetFeatureCount()
layer.ResetReading()
defn = layer.GetLayerDefn()`
Nothing improves the situation.

Comment: Does it changes anything if you try to change the -1 to 1 like this in the `driver.Open(shape_filename, 1)`?

Comment: my suggestion is to include ALL of your code...it will prevent us from guessing what is there and what is not.

Comment: @user1269942 This is the code, it's reproductible.

Answer (score 0):

The vector tutorial in the gdal documentation provides a good example for writing a wkbPoint feature, but writing a wkbPolygon feature is a little trickier. Below is (c++) code works for me. (Note: TMultline is just an externally defined linked list of vertices.)

```
bool TTdhOGR_target::WriteLinePts (OGRFeature *poFeature, TMultiLine *lineParam) {
  OGRLinearRing lineString;
  OGRPolygon currPoly;
  TVertex *currPt = lineParam->get_firstPt();
  while (currPt) {
    lineString.addPoint(currPt->getX(), currPt->getY());
    currPt = (TVertex*)currPt->next();
    }
  currPoly.addRing(&lineString);
  return (poFeature->SetGeometry(&currPoly) == OGRERR_NONE);
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).